# why when i send with ajax, _session php undifined?

Tags: php, ajax, session

i have a 3 php file

```
--index
 ---formpage
 ---actpage
```

insisde of index i was call session_start(); the **formpage** and **actpage** is content of index.php when my form send with basicly (without ajax) _SESSION was defined but why when i try with ajax _SESSION has Undifined?

someone can help me?

Comment: can you pls share your code/.

Comment: Are you passing the page to the URL of the same domain and / or sub-domain and also the same protocall?

Comment: could you please post your code and your ajax request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include `session_start()` at the first of **formpage** and **actpage** the requested page by your ajax code